# keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, io

I copied and pasted the line below into Mac terminal:
jar ufm Client.jar addToManifest.txt

at the time, I didn't realize the rest of the line was highlighted as well, which automatically submitted the text for me. Not knowing this, I hit enter myself as well. This caused the following error thereafter:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Client.jar (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:259)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1233)
```

To make things worse, or if relevant whatsoever, the original Client.jar that this was put under was deleted from trash/garbage bin. So I have no access to this original jar file as well.

Now, every time I try this:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore testkeys -alias stathis
```

I get the following error:

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

How do I restore my Keystore alteration? I've checked other questions of this error to no avail. Please keep in mind I use a Mac, so some things that I must do in terminal are "Permission denied"'ed. I have done something terrible in no later than 5 seconds. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The two aren't related. All that's happened here is that you've forgotten your keystore password, or possibly created a zero length or otherwise invalid keystore.

Comment: No, I have the password written down next to me. Could it be that I entered in  jar ufm Client.jar addToManifest.txt twice? Once more after I accidentally entered it twice to start over and be sure that the process was done right?

Comment: Modifying a JAR file doesn't affect the keystore. What else did you do around that time? Is the keystore file a reasonable length? When you 'cat' it, does it look like a JAR file?